# How do I remove tick labels in latex using pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, labels

On my old Mac running OS 10.4.11, using TeXShop 2.26 I would use the pstricks package to draw figures.  In those figures I had neither tick marks nor tick labels.  I have recently switched to a new Macbook running OS 10.82 and have downloaded the latest TeXShop 3.11.  When I try to compile my old files in the new LaTeX everything works fine, except that my figures now show up with tick labels (not tick marks).  When I rerun the same files in my old Macbook the tick marks do not show up.  Can anyone please tell me what is going on?  Is there a way I can remove the tick labels in pstricks?  Also, should I be switching to a different graphics package?

Answer (score 6):

```
...[ticks=none,labels=none,...]{...}
```

or global for all:

```
\psset{ticks=none,labels=none}
```